# Best way to remove trailing period for a.m., p.m

Tags: javascript, django, templates, filter

I'm outputting a string in my Django template that contains "a.m." or "p.m.". I'd like to remove/filter-out the trailing period if it falls at the end of a sentence. This is to avoid "a.m.." or "p.m..".

What's the best way to do this in Django? Or is this something I should do via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery to the rescue:

```
<script>
$("#special_today").text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace("..", ".");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Assumes the offending period occurs within an element with the ID "special_today".

Comment: Including jQuery just for this seems pretty stupid for me. You could just use `.textContent` instead of `.text` here and use vanilla JS

Comment: I'm using jQuery for Bootstrap as well, not just for this solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for some strange reason there aren't other sentences ending with `m..`

```
str = str.replace(/m\.\./g, 'm.');
```